# NPE when pulling or pushing with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit

I recently updated to *Eclipse 2023-03*.

Now I get a NullPointerException on each push or pull in my git repository.

The error log shows this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "java.lang.Enum.toString()" because "defaultValue" is null
    at org.eclipse.egit.core.internal.ReportingTypedConfigGetter.getEnum(ReportingTypedConfigGetter.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.lib.Config.getEnum(Config.java:449)
    at org.eclipse.jgit.api.PullCommand.getRebaseMode(PullCommand.java:534)
```

Sometimes I only see it in the error log and nothing happens when pressing *Pull* or *Push*.

As I can see, it has something to do with the *rebase mode* (which is configured in the branch). But I can't open the *Branch configuration...* from the context menu of the branch either, because of the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=581806

The value `preserve` for the `rebase` property was renamed to `merges` and the configuration stumbles if it finds the old value in the current branch.

If you replace `preserve` with `merges` in the properties of the repository for each branch, push and pull will work again.